# Why is are classes from a required bundle not found while building an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

I'm using Xtext and have several plugins.

One is called harpo.plugin. In its Manifest.MF file we have

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: harpo.plugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Export-Package: harpo.plugin;uses:="org.eclipse.xtext,org.eclipse.xtext.common.types,com.google.inject",
 harpo.plugin.editor;uses:="org.eclipse.emf.ecore,org.eclipse.emf.common.util",
[... much omitted ... ]
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: org.apache.log4j,
 org.eclipse.jface.viewers,
 org.eclipse.ui
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Now a second plugin called harpo.plugin.ui depends on harpo.plugin. Its Manifest.MF looks like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Ui
Bundle-SymbolicName: harpo.plugin.ui;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: harpo.plugin.ui.internal.EditorActivator
Export-Package: harpo.plugin.ui,
 harpo.plugin.ui.contentassist,
 harpo.plugin.ui.contentassist.antlr,
 harpo.plugin.ui.internal,
 harpo.plugin.ui.quickfix
Require-Bundle: harpo.plugin;bundle-version="1.0.0",
 [...much omitted...]
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Import-Package: org.apache.log4j
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Now when I compile the latter plugin, all the java files that depend on classes defined in harpo.plugin.editor have errors `Type can not be resolved.`

My question: What could cause these errors?

If I add the harpo.plugin project to the "Build path" of harpo.plugin.ui project, all compiles.  But I shouldn't have to do that, right?  In fact I probably shouldn't do that, right?

Comment: The Libraries section of the Java Build Path should have a 'Plug-in Dependencies' section. This should have been added automatically (and comes from a `org.eclipse.pde.core.requiredPlugins` entry in the `.classpath` file).

Comment: Thanks. There is a "Plug-in Dependencies" section in the Java Build Path of the `harpo.plugin.ui` but the `harpo.plugin` is not on the list.  So I used the magic command "Plugin tools >> Update Classpath...", selected the missing project, clicked on "Finish", but the project is still not in the classpath.

Comment: Also. I tried deleting the 'Plugin Dependencies" section. This seemed to work -- i.e. it was really gone.  Then rebuilt it with "Plugin tools >> Update Classpath...". Still no joy!

Comment: Shutdown Eclipse. Restarted Eclipse. Problem gone!